# jQuery Load Div Content from Current Page to Another Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have seen some example of loading HTML content to page from an outside of the current page like

```
$("#divData").load("article.html #target");
```

Now I need to do some thing completely visa versa! I mean I need to export a portion of my current active page to an existing .php page on the server. For example if I have an HTML like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="well"> 
   <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Left</button>
    <button class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button class="btn">Right</button>
   </div>
   <button id="loader" class="btn btn-default">Load To PHP Page</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I export/Load the `well` content with it's entire elements to a `.PHP` lets say print.php page which is like this:

```
<?php

    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $codigo= '<html>
                <body>
                </body>
              </html>';

    $codigo = utf8_decode($codigo);
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($codigo);
    ini_set("memory_limit","32M");
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("ejemplo.pdf");
```

Update:

```
Data returned from PHP: %PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [6 0 R
]
/Count 1
/Resources <<
/ProcSet 4 0 R
/Font << 
/F1 8 0 R
>>
>>
/MediaBox [0.000 0.000 612.000 792.000]
 >>
endobj
4 0 obj
[/PDF /Text ]
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Creator (DOMPDF)
/CreationDate (D:20140425170443+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20140425170443+00'00')
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Contents 7 0 R
>>
endobj
7 0 obj
<<
/Length 71 >>
stream

0.000 0.000 0.000 rg
BT 34.016 746.579 Td /F1 12.0 Tf  [(salam)] TJ ET
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/Name /F1
/BaseFont /Times-Roman
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000008 00000 n 
0000000073 00000 n 
0000000119 00000 n 
0000000273 00000 n 
0000000302 00000 n 
0000000416 00000 n 
0000000479 00000 n 
0000000600 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 9
/Root 1 0 R
/Info 5 0 R
>>
startxref
710
%%EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the whole state of the active page, you can just submit a form that has an input wich contains the HTML you want. You can also do the same in AJAX if that's what you want.

E.g.

HTML

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="htmlContent">
    <button type="submit">Submit HTML</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    $(this).children('[name=htmlContent]').val($('.well').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options, first to answer your question, you could send the contents of `div.well` with ajax to `print.php`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'print.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        yourData: $('div.well').html()
    },
    success: function(msg) {
        alert('Data returned from PHP: ' + msg);
        // now do something with your returned data, liked load it in a new window.
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('AJAX request failed! ' + xhr.status + ' ' + thrownError);
    }
});
```

You can then `echo $_POST['yourData'];` on your `print.php` page to use the `div.well` on that page.

Or you could just put your `.load("page.html div.well")` on your `print.php` page if the loaded content is static (see comments below).

Comment: Using `load` on the remote page would only work if you do not expect to preserve the state of the loaded page (given that it would be dynamic).

Comment: Hi hemerlinproject thanks but I am getting AJAX request failed! error here

Comment: @Behseini, the code I provided above is sample code, without your exact file names and paths I can't troubleshoot with you. Most likely it is a path error of the "url". Trying putting the exact path is there, e.g. 'http ://yourdomain/any_directories/print.php'

Comment: try the above code to see if we can get some more data about the error

Comment: themerlinproject, Thanks again but after checking every thing I am getting above updated long text and nothing in PDF!

Comment: the function above will send the div.well, which is what you asked. The PDF functionality of your code is another question entirely. I would first ensure that the the div is sent correctly using a dummy.php file, then make sure that the PDF is displaying correctly on its own, and then work on combining the two.

Comment: I would point the ajax toward dummy.php, create dummy.php that will echo $_POST['yourData'] (this is where ajax is sending your div.well), then run the ajax function and view the result. It should alert you with the contents of div.well.

Comment: No thanks. The above code does what you asked. I've given you what I would do to troubleshoot it. Now you have to troubleshoot it yourself. If you have another specific question then ask a new question.

Comment: ok this the error message I am getting on printing the result : Notice: Undefined index: yourData in G:\Apps\Server\root\PDF3\pdf.php on line 2