# Issue on Registering and Using jQuery in domPDF Library

Tags: php, jquery, dompdf

I need to load some html content dynamically based on user selection to a print.php page which using PHP dompdf library to export html to PDF.
Now I have to include jQuery and some other js libraries  to my html but it seems jquery is not registering correctly (or even not at all). in following example I just tried to simple insert text into `#result` by using `.html()` but I am getting empty PDF on output.

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");
$codigo= '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#result" ).html( "This is Test" );
});
</script>
</body>
</html> 
';
$codigo = utf8_decode($codigo);
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($codigo);
ini_set("memory_limit","32M");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("ejemplo.pdf");
```

can you please let me know if this doable or what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any errors in console? Try `jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {` in case the $ variable is not set yet.

Comment: Thanks  themerlinproject, I already check this it seems the dompdf is not taking any js library. By the way , did you see my last post on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298701/jquery-load-div-content-from-current-page-to-another-page/23298864#23298864 ?

Comment: Try moving your script tags into the `head` tags

Answer (score 0):

dompdf only supports HTML+CSS. JavaScript (and thus jQuery) is not supported at all. For dompdf to render any content dynamically generated via JavaScript you would have to capture the page contents in the browser and send it back to the server. You could use a hidden form, capture the relevant content from the document, insert it into a `textarea` field in the form, then submit that back to the server/dompdf for rendering.

If you want full browser compatibility in your render you'll need to look at something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).